# Creating an html from the output of awk script

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk, html

I am performing in an awk script a series of aggregations from a dataset and I get the following.

Now I would like to create an html that collects this previous output in the form of a table and that also makes a bar graph taking into account the values of a, b, c. I want the code for the html to be in this script too.

**UPDATE SAMPLE OF THE DATASET TO GENERATE AGGREGATIONS**

```
Bel,BLR,897,965322,6844,102217,725,
Bel,BEL,976,3851048,30826,329772,
Ben,BEN,9765,26952,163,2126,13,
Bot,BWA,976,305526,2686,125488,1103,
Cabo,CPV,9865,55960,401,98772,708,
```

**UPDATE AGGREGATED_DATA OUTPUT**

```
7,5.23,6.36,0.63
6,12.56,24.64,0.53 
9,0.63,32.8,3.35
```

My script is as follows:

```
END {
                print "<html><body>"
                print "<table border=1>"
} NR == 1 {
                print "<tr>"
                print "<td><font face=verdana size=2 color=black>" $k "</font></td>"
                print "<td><font face=verdana size=2 color=black>" $c "</font></td>"
                print "<td><font face=verdana size=2 color=black>" $a "</font></td>"
                print "<td><font face=verdana size=2 color=black>" $aa "</font></td>"
                print "<td><font face=verdana size=2 color=black>" $aaa "</font></td>"
                print "</tr>"
} NR > 1 {
                print "<tr>"
                print "<td><font face=verdana size=1>" $1 "</font></td>"
                print "<td><font face=verdana size=1>" $2 "</font></td>"
                print "<td><font face=verdana size=1>" $3 "</font></td>"
                print "</tr>"
} END {
                print "</table>"
                print "</body></html>"
}

> file.html
```

Any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

HTML as such cannot "collect this previous output in the form of a table and also make a bar graph taking into account the values of a, b, c.". If you want this to happen when loading a html page, you need to make use of some web scripting language. You did not provide detail, but if the data processing is on the web server, server side scripting languages include PHP, Python, Ruby, C#, and JavaScript. For processing on the client side, javascript is common but that is typically quite insecure.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make use of an existing framework, such as `Google Libraries API`,
to generate an html graph on the fly.
Assuming a file `agreggated_data.csv` consists of the shown table, would you
please try the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
# generate strings based on the input file
str1=$(awk -F, '
    NR==1 {
        printf "\t[%s,", "\047" "\047"
        for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", "\047" $i "\047", i == NF ? "],\n" : ","
        }
    }
    NR>1 {
        printf "\t[%s,", "\047" $1 "\047"
        for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) {
            printf "%s%s", $i, i == NF ? "],\n" : ","
        }
    }
' aggregated_data.csv)

str2=$(awk -F, '
    NR>1 {
        printf "    formatter3.format(data3,%d);\n", ++n
    }
' aggregated_data.csv)

# embed generated strings in the template to create "file.html"
cat <<EOS > file.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
// load api
google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

// callback
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

// function to draw the graph
function drawChart(){
    var data3 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
$str1
    ]);

    var formatter3 = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        pattern: '#,###.##'
    });
$str2

    var options3 = {
        chartArea: {width:'55%', height:'75%',left:50},
        colors:['#4477cc','#55cc55','#ff7788'],
        legend: {position:'right'},
        fontName:"sans-serif",
        tooltip:{textStyle:{bold:'false'}},
        bar:{groupWidth:"70%"},
        hAxis:{
            textStyle:{fontSize:11}
        },
        vAxis:{
            format:'#,###.##',
            gridlines: {count:6},
            textStyle:{fontSize:11}
        },
        isStacked:true,
        backgroundColor:'transparent'
    };

    var chart3 = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('Chart3'));
    chart3.draw(data3, options3);
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.chart{
    width:450px;
    height:350px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="chartBox">
    <div id="Chart3" class="chart"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
EOS
```

Here is the generated graph (`file.html`).

[image: Generated graph]

As I'm not sure about your desired layout/view of the graph (e.g. how we
use the value of `Total`), additional feedback are welcome.

Comment: Hello thsiono. Nice to see you here. Your code looks very good. However I tried it and it didn't work :( Actually the table in the post is an aggregation of a large dataset and I would like the code for the aggregation (which already works) and the code to generate the html to be in the same script. Below I put in edit what I have tried from yours.

Comment: You can find what I've tried in **UPDATE** on my post. Maybe I'm not doing something properly...

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Does it work well if you invoke your script (which generates `aggregated_data.csv`) and my script (which reads `aggregated_data.csv`) separately?

Comment: BTW how do you run your `awk` script? Does it look like `awk -f yourscript.awk dataset.csv`?

Comment: I need to run it as gawk -f script.awk dataset.csv :)

Comment: As my script is `bash`, you need to modify your code to be embedded in bash. Please take a look of my updated answer.

Comment: Hi! @tshiono Sorry to bother you. I have run the script and it generates aggregated_data without the header and with commas between the values (see table update in my post) unlike before it was without commas. On the other hand, the script runs correctly without errors but when entering firefox file.html I don't see any result.

Comment: One problem is you have misspelled `aggregated_data.csv` as
`agreggated_data.csv` which generates two files: just a header file
and a file w/o the header. Another problem is your previous `table`
uses whitespaces as a delimiter (this was the only input I could use
to generate the html file) while your awk script generates a csv.
Now I have fixed my script accordingly. The posted `dataset.csv` file
is helpful. I should have asked you to provide it earlier.